# Ruby on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue with a nested model in my application. I can't get the values to show. I know I have to do it like this: @modelname.attribute (view), but it doesn't seem to work. That's why I started to look in the console if everything I did in the controller was right.
Everything seems ok. But I have one question, in the console, when you do this (example):

```
@modelname = Modelname.find(an id)
```

it gives you the corresponding object like this:

```
=>#< Modelname, id: x, other attributes >
```

and when I'm trying to find my other object in the console, I get this:

```
=>[#< Modelname, id: x, other attributes >]
```

Why? What's the difference and could that be my problem?

Comment: What does "find my other object" mean? Finding by ID returns a single object. A `has_many` association will return an array (sort of) even if there are no associated records, or a single one. But we can't see what you're actually doing, what your models look like, etc.

Comment: So I have a patients table in my database and a katz table. The katz table has the patient_id. Now what I want is to put all the values of the katz object in hiddenfields. And for that I'm using `<%= hidden_field_tag 'katz[wash]', @katz.wash %>` The wash is an attribute of the katz object, but I always get the same error: NoMethodError, undefined method wash. For my associations I have this : `has_many :katz`and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :katz`in patient.rb and in katz.rb I have: `belongs_to :patient`

Comment: Edit the question instead of cramming it all into a comment.  include the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

The second time –in the console– you're getting an array. That's the difference. As of why, we don't know what your wrote to find the model, but you must be calling `ModelName.where` or one fo the other methods in the ActiveRecord query API that returns an array (an ActiveRecord::Relation to be precise)

Comment: So I have a patients table in my database and a katz table. The katz table has the patient_id. Now what I want is to put all the values of the katz object in hiddenfields. And for that I'm using <%= hidden_field_tag 'katz[wash]', @katz.wash %> The wash is an attribute of the katz object, but I always get the same error: NoMethodError, undefined method wash. For my associations I have this : has_many :katzand accepts_nested_attributes_for :katzin patient.rb and in katz.rb I have: belongs_to :patient

Comment: I recommend that you post a new question for this. In any case, the symbol in has_many must be plural (katz(s)?). That may be the cause of your problems.